# How does this method being called with CLASS macro work?

Tags: c++

I recently received a request from an acquaintance to assist with building a C++ solution after their developer unfortunately passed away.  I'm relatively new to C++ and don't quite understand what the following lines are doing.

This code is from a customized version of the dcraw.cpp library by Dave Coffin.

The MACRO is defined as

```
#define CLASS
```

The method being called looks like this

```
 void CLASS merror (void *ptr, char *where)
{
     if ( ptr ) return;
     //fprintf (stderr,_("%s: Out of memory in %s\n"), ifname, where);
     sprintf (PSstring(),"%s: Out of memory in %s\n", ifname, where);
     PSputDiag ();
     longjmp (failure, 1);
}
```

And the method call looks like this

```
merror (fimg, "wavelet_denoise()");
```

When trying to compile the code I receive about 1800 errors, 258 of which are similar to the following.

> C2664 'void merror(void *,char *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [15]' to 'char *'  Photoshoot5 C:\Users\source\projectname\MVDcraw.cpp 991

I've been searching for quite some time to figure out what is going on, but since I don't even know what the method call is doing I've been unable to find anything that is relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `CLASS` is irrelevant.  `"wavelet_denoise()"` is a constant string literal and `merror` expects an non-const.  Change `char *where` to `char const *where`.  Also `longjmp` in a C++ program is a big red flag _"...No destructors for automatic objects are called...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp.

Comment: Change the prototype to `void CLASS merror(void *ptr, const char *where)`. You can omit the `CLASS` part entirely unless some other tool or utility needs it. (Some compilers used to allow passing character strings as `char *` as an extension.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro

> #define CLASS

has nothing to do with your error. After the macro is expanded the function is:

```
 void merror (void *ptr, char *where)
{
     if ( ptr ) return;
     //fprintf (stderr,_("%s: Out of memory in %s\n"), ifname, where);
     sprintf (PSstring(),"%s: Out of memory in %s\n", ifname, where);
     PSputDiag ();
     longjmp (failure, 1);
}
```

That is, the macro is replaced by nothing.

The code appears to be written before C++11. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)...

until C++11:

> String literals are convertible and assignable to non-const char* or wchar_t* in order to be compatible with C, where string literals are of types char[N] and wchar_t[N]. Such implicit conversion is deprecated.

since C++11:

> String literals are not convertible or assignable to non-const CharT*. An explicit cast (e.g. const_cast) must be used if such conversion is wanted.

Converting string literals to `char*` never was ok, but only since C++11 it is an error. If you are using C++17 you can use `std::string::data()`:

```
 std::string where{"wavelet_denoise()"};
 merror (fimg, where.data());
```

Actually better would be to change the method, as suggested in a comment by Richard Critten, to take a `const char* where`.